# Do not show if 1 variables are equal to 0 and the other one is empty in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I don't know why I can't make this condition work. First I'll show you may foreach table.

```
@foreach( $w1ProductHistory as $w1ph )
    @php
    $totalCost = $w1ph->orderItem->cost * $w1ph->stock_in_qty;
    @endphp
    @if($w1ph->stock_in_qty!='0' && $w1ph->delivery_note!='')
    <tr>
        <td>{{$w1ph->orderItem->product_code}}</td>
        <td>{{$w1ph->orderItem->product_name}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ URL('/orders/'.$w1ph->order->id)}}" class="text-info">{{$w1ph->order->purchase_no}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$w1ph->delivery_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$w1ph->companies->comp_name}}</td> 
        <td>{{$w1ph->orderItem->cost}}</td>
        <td>{{$w1ph->stock_in_qty}}</td>
        <td>{{number_format($totalCost)}}</td>
        <td>
            @if(isset($w1ph->delivery_note))
                <a data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delivery Notes: {{$w1ph->delivery_note}}" href="{{-- {{ route('orders.edit',$order->id) }} --}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default"><i class="fab fa-readme"></i></a>
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

What I am trying to do is to hide if only **$w1ph->stock_in_qty!='0** and **$w1ph->delivery_note!=''**.

if **$w1ph->stock_in_qty!='0** but **$w1ph->delivery_note!=''** has value, the row should be display.

I already tried `@if($w1ph->stock_in_qty!='0' && $w1ph->delivery_note!='')` , `@if($w1ph->stock_in_qty!='0' && !empty($w1ph->delivery_note))` even changing the "&&" to and. still it hides the row even with only one condition is met.

Again, I am trying to hide the row only if both condition is meet not either 1 of them. How can I achieve it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it totaly legal code to have the @php tags in the blade file, but you might reconsider if you really need to do it like that.

Why? Because it makes your blade file cleaner and you should strive for keeping the blade files without any other logic than getting attributes/relationsships.
Also if you need to do that calculation at some other place in your application you have it on the model, and should the algorithm behind the value change, you just have to change it one place.

The better solution, in my opionon, is to define an attribute on your ProductHistory(?) model which gives you this value and just do $w1ph->totalCost;

Also i would add an attribute which returns a boolean based on you need to show this item in the table or not, something like $w1ph->showInTable/visible/showDisplay, etc.

Have you tried without the qutoes around the 0? or count($w1ph-->stock_in_qty) == 0)?

Comment: thanks @kapalua no I haven't yet. I'll try it now. And also thank you for the this tip I'll do that next time. actually this is my first try using php frameworks. this tip will surely noted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try something like

```
    @if(count($w1ph->stock_in_qty)>0)&& (count($w1ph->delivery_note)>0))

@endif
```